# Change database query at runtime

Tags: delphi, filtering, delphi-2010, firebird2.5, dbgrid

I'm trying to filter a `TDBGrid` via a `TEdit`, handling the `TEdit` `onChange` event.
I have a `TIBQuery` to list all the records in the grid:

```
SELECT id,obra,cliente,fecha,nro_estudio,sondeo FROM proyecto;
```

When the user inserts characters in the `TEdit`, the grid must be refreshed by the `Cliente` field.

My code tries to do this, but when it executes the handler, the query returns an empty resultset. I'm using Firebird 2.5 and IB Components.

Relevant Code:

```
query := Self.qryTodos;
query.Close();
query.SQL.Clear();
query.SQL.Add('SELECT id,obra,cliente,fecha,nro_estudio,sondeo FROM proyecto WHERE cliente LIKE :Cliente');
query.ParamByName('Cliente').AsString := QuotedStr('%'+Self.busqueda.Text+'%');
query.Open();
DMConnect.Transaction.Commit();
```

Comment: Remove/comment the last line (`DMConnect.Transaction.Commit();`) and try again. By committing the transaction you're implicitly closing all attached datasets.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need QuotedStr when you're supplying string parameters.   By using it, you make it not match any more  (e.g. "String" becomes '''%String%''')

Comment: I try this `...LIKE ' + '%''' + Self.busqueda.Text + '%'''`. But, the program ¿crash? with this message: "Attempt to execute an unprepared dynamic SQL statment"

Comment: Couple problems there:   if you still have the parameter referent (:Cliente), the query needs to be assigned parameter values before executing.    Also, in the expression above, you're adding the wildcard *before* the opening quote in the string: that won't parse correctly.    Also, as a side-note, if your string value has any embedded single quotes, that approach will break--it's better to use parameters to construct query strings.

Answer (score 0):

If you're surrounding your search term in % I would use the *containing* clause, so you could write your query like:

```
query := Self.qryTodos;
query.Close();
query.SQL.Clear();
query.SQL.Add('SELECT id,obra,cliente,fecha,nro_estudio,sondeo FROM proyecto WHERE cliente CONTAINING :Cliente');
query.ParamByName('Cliente').AsString := Self.busqueda.Text;
query.Open();
```

and remove the Commit statement as @LightBulb stated.  This will work if you want to include the % in your search term for any reason.